# CMD IF EXIST with variable

Tags: batch-file, cmd

When checking whether a directory exists, this works

```
 if exist "M:\folder\" echo ok
```

But this does not

```
set thedir = "M:\folder"
if exist %thedir% echo ok
```

Ultimately, I am checking to see if a folder has been created with the current date

```
set CUR_YYYY=%date:~10,4%
set CUR_MM=%date:~4,2%
set CUR_DD=%date:~7,2%

if exist "SomePath\" %YYYY%_%MM%_%DD% echo ok
```

Comment: Is `"M:\folder"` a typo? Did you mean `"M:\folder\"`?

Comment: Yes M:\folder\  is what I meant. This is a directory.

Comment: `set thedir = "M:\folder"` sets the value of the variable `thedir[space]` to the value `[Space]"M:\folder"`. Remove the spaces around the `=` and preferably use the syntax `set "var=value"` which avoids the problems with trailing spaces on code lines being assigned as part of the value and allows elements to be more easily manipulated.

Comment: That was it. There was a space behind the =. After all these years, it's the syntax that will kill ya. Thank you.

Comment: *N. B.:* `if exist "M:\folder"` evaluates to true even if `M:\folder` is a file rather than a directory; `if exist "M:\folder\"` returns true for directories on local drives but may also react on files on network drives; the most reliable way I know of is `if exist "M:\folder\*"`…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spaces matter.

```
set thedir = "M:\folder"
rem       ↑ ↑
```

creates variable `thedir<space>` and assigns the value `<space>"M:\folder"`

Use (see https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)

```
set "thedir=M:\folder"
if exist "%thedir%" echo ok
```

For the other example enclose *entire* tested path in double quotes as follows:

```
if exist "SomePath\%YYYY%_%MM%_%DD%" echo ok
```